# Mysql grant privileges get error ERROR 1133 (42000): Can't find any matching row in the user table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to grant priv to my django user, but I got error says can't find any matching row in the user table.
It is the user table.

`mysql> select user,grant_priv from user;
+---------------+------------+
| user          | grant_priv |
+---------------+------------+
| root          | Y          |
| mysql.session | N          |
| mysql.sys     | N          |
| django        | N          |
+---------------+------------+`

Here is databases.

`mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| django             |
| my_First_Django    |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+`

I used code below and got the error.

`mysql> grant all privileges on django.* to django@localhost identified by '';
ERROR 1133 (42000): Can't find any matching row in the user table`
btw I tried `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` as well, and not work.

Anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run from Root user:

```
grant all privileges on django.* to 'django'@'localhost' identified by '';
```

## EDIT- Example

```
mysql> grant all privileges on testdb1.* to 'user1'@'localhost' identified by 'user1';                                                         Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.01 sec)

mysql> flush privileges;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
```

Comment: I did run from Root user, and got the err.

Comment: I mean I did run from Root at first time, and the error is `ERROR 1133 (42000): Can't find any matching row in the user table`

Comment: Did you created the user in "django" user in MySQL if not then in my example just pass your username instead MySQL of "user1" , so it will create the user as well as give the permission. If user already exists then just change the "user1" with your correct user and run it from MySQL root user. It will work for you.

Comment: In information is useful you may mark this question answered.

Comment: I did, but it says under 15 reputation won't display publicly